# How To Run HipHop/HHVM Using Build Ubuntu

Tags: php, facebook, ubuntu, hhvm

I followed this tutorial for installing here:

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-13.04

But I can't figure out how to run it. I've gone to  to the hphp/hhvm/hhvm and I've run this on hhhm

```
root@hhvm-ubuntu:~/dev/hiphop-php/hphp/hhvm# ls
CMakeFiles           CMakeLists.txt        hhvm          main.cpp  process_init.cpp
cmake_install.cmake  global_variables.cpp  link_hphp.sh  Makefile  process_init.h
```

The problem is each time I run, the server crashes. Actually the server is slow with hhvm install, its a 1 GB instance on Rackspace. But how am I suppose to run hip-hop after compiling from source?

Answer (score 1):

You just run `hphp/hhvm/hhvm some_file.php` if you want it in command line or `hphp/hhvm/hhvm -m server /some/document_root/` for a server. Look on the wiki for more config information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the link handy, but 1 gb is not enough to run HipHopVM. The process itself will easily chew up that amount of ram by itself. When it chews up more ram than you have it will slow to a crawl and then eventually crash.

Try using it in a 4gig instance. You may have better luck.

Take a look at [this article for some more info on configuring hhvm](http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/fv-b-8-656/adventures-in-configuring-and-running-facebook-s-hiphopvm--hhvm--jit-compiler-for-php.html).